# Boot Camp - Apple SD Card Reader not recognised

Tags: bootcamp, windows, usb, startup, sd-card

I've issues with my Boot Camp instance. The following happened/happens:
- my JetDrive SDXC Card is shown on Mac OS Catalina and works properly;
- I installed carefully Windows 10 with Boot Camp Assistant;
- I previously downloaded Windows support files on usb stick;
- I downloaded ISO of Windows 10, using other Windows PC and Media Creation Tool available from Microsoft site;
- I created bootable USB drive using Boot Camp Assistant;
- I installed and chose Windows 10 Pro Version, after installation I installed Windows Support files - Setup.exe
- Everything seems to work correctly, Wi-Fi, usb ports, screen, sound etc.
- except for Apple SD Card Reader;
**- The problem really starts here;**
- Device Manager shows no such thing as Apple SD Card Reader or anything similar;
- The same goes for dskmgmt;
- Different solutions posted on different sites have I tried, but nothing have helped;

Have you any idea on how to solve this issue?

Issue happens on *basic* version of Macbook Pro 13" (Mid 2014).

Kind Regards,
JC

Comment: Just so you know, the Media Creation Tool downloads a different ISO than the ISO available from the Microsoft website the [Apple instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468) recommend. Also, have you tried Windows Update and Apple Software Update to see if any new drivers are available?

Comment: I will try with the one you said, although I think that Windows is Windows and it's dependent on a drivers, so the issue should be on the driver side.  
  
However, I tried Windows Update, Apple Software Update, and tried different ways of installing drivers, but it showed it's all good.

Comment: I agree. I was just pointing out the two ISO are not the same. The main difference is one has an `install.esd` and the other has an `install.wim`. There probably is no difference once decompressed.

Comment: I did as you said, which is using the Windows Apple recommended. No difference, all the same, still doesn't see the SD Card reader and Card itself

Comment: The only other suggestion would be to try the a BIOS install of Windows. This is possible because you have a 2014 model which can either boot BIOS or UEFI boot Windows. However, Apple does not officially support running BIOS booting Windows 10 on any Mac model. I only suggest this because the set of drivers would be different.

Comment: I will give it a shot. How do I do it then? I just do it manually like on any other laptop, make a bootable USB and boot it from boot menu?